# How do I chain together layout change animations with the LayoutTransition class or otherwise?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a [ViewGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup) on which I have set the `android:animateLayoutChanges` property to `true`.

As a result, when I toggle the visibility of one of the Views in the [ViewGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup) between [View.VISIBLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#VISIBLE) and [View.GONE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#GONE), I get a nice layout change animation as follows:

[image: Animated layout changes]

I'd like to take this idea a step further and chain together a sequence of transitions. For example, hide "Two" and then show "Three".

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to achieve this as follows:

1. Define a [LayoutTransition.TransitionListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition.TransitionListener) which sets the visibility of the View that I want to show as [View.VISIBLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#VISIBLE) when the [endTransition(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition.TransitionListener#endTransition(android.animation.LayoutTransition,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.view.View,%20int)) method is called.
2. Get the [LayoutTransition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition) object in the [ViewGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup) and add the [LayoutTransition.TransitionListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition.TransitionListener) defined in step 1 to it.
3. Set the visibility of the View that I want to hide as [View.GONE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#GONE).

This achieves a sequence of animations as follows:

[image: Animated layout changes]

This works but seems a little fragile and is a somewhat clumsy solution for scenarios where I need to add a third or fourth animation to the sequence.

If anybody has suggestions for a simpler means of chaining together layout change animations, I'm open to it.

#### Notes

1. My description of the implementation above is a little simplified and omits some work I'm doing to remove the [LayoutTransition.TransitionListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition.TransitionListener) when a given transition ends. For the concrete details, see [here](https://github.com/adil-hussain-84/android-animation-experiments/blob/master/app1/src/main/java/com/tazkiyatech/animation/experiments/MainActivity.kt).